# Can I ignore rest of the list when the pattern occurs java?

Tags: java

This is the Code:

```
private List listaPunktowInt(List lista) {
    
    String liniaString="";
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList();
    Iterator<String> it=lista.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        liniaString=it.next();
        
        if(Pattern.matches("\\d*",liniaString)) {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(liniaString));
        }
    }
    
    //Collections.sort(list);
    //Collections.reverse(list);
    System.out.println(list);
    return list;
}

Input:[56, 4, 2 2022 04 06, 1, 1, 1]

Output:[56, 4, 1, 1, 1]
```

I want "2" to be included as well but the rest ("2022 04 06") to be ignored, is it possible?

Comment: Please [avoid raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). The argument should be `List<String> lista` and `list` should be declared/initialized as `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: *"I want "2" to be included as well but the rest ("2022 04 06")"* - Does it imply you need only the *first character* of every string or this applies only to strings representing a date? Why there's no issue with `56`?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I want all characters before space to be a single int. The "2" or "56" represent a points and the rest date.

Comment: What if one of the strings is `"123foo"`? Or just `"foo"`? Or the empty string `""`? How should the code behave then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now `Pattern.matches` checks if *the whole string* matches `\d*` (i.e. only contains digits). That's very easy with the static `Pattern.matches` method.

To do anything more involved with regex, you should use [a `Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) (which is the thing that is about a single *use* of a regex, i.e. it's the combination of a pattern like `\d*` and some input string like `liniaString`). It' still used under the hood, but `Pattern.matches` hides that fact from you.

So your code could look like this (I also fixed the types and added `static` since the method doesn't depend on any state of the object):

```
private static List<Integer> listaPunktowInt(List<String> lista) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\d+");
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for (String liniaString : lista) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(liniaString);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Right now this simply takes as many digits from the beginning as possible and ignores whatever comes after them (characters, space, end of string, ...). If you want something other than that, you can adapt the pattern used.

Comment: @molyyyllom: you're welcome. Note that it's not necessary to write individual thank you comments on SO. It's sufficient to upvote answers (and questions!) that help you. If you want you can also accept answers. Doing either of that is actually preferred to writing "thank you" comments.